# Angular ng-options remove blank option and select the first option only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ng-options

I am using AngularJS to populate my select options content dynamically from an array of objects in my controller. My objects has a property named **userProfileName**.

How would it be possible to remove the blank option that I am getting at the top?

Also, I would want to select the first profile **Profile 1** by default. How can this be done?

My Snippet of code is here:

```
<select id="requestorSite" 
                             ng-model="selectedUserProfile"
                             ng-options="userProfile.userProfileName for userProfile in userProfiles"
                             ng-selected=""
                             class="form-control displayInlineBlock width40per marginLeft15">
                            </select>
```

My controller has

```
$scope.userProfiles
```

As the array of object and each object has **userProfileName** attribute.

Below is the screen shot:
[image]

I would like to remove the blank option at the top and also have by default **Profile 1** selected.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do this :)

In your controller :

```
 function myCtrl ($scope) {
   $scope.userProfiles = [
     {id: 10, name: 'Carton'},
     {id: 27, name: 'Bernard'},
     {id: 39, name: 'Julie'},
  ];

   $scope.selectedUserProfile= $scope.userProfiles[0]; // Set by default the   value "carton"
  };
```

In your page :

```
      <select  id="requestorSite" ng-model="selectedUserProfile" ng-options="userProfile as userProfile.name for userProfile in userProfiles">
            </select>
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdOGVB

Comment: Now I am looking for blank options problem

Comment: Blank options problem ? This code put value in the select but he also put a default value, so the blank problems would be solved. Show us your code please.

Comment: Its written on the top... pick your same example... you will also get blank option.

Comment: If you put ng-model="myModel", this line remove the blank option :
       $scope.myModel= $scope.userProfiles[0];

Comment: I did the same thing. $scope.selectedUserProfile = $scope.userProfiles[0].userProfileName; Still Not Working.

Comment: Have a look to litle codepen, you will understand : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdOGVB

Answer (score 0):

This has several solution. The following worked best for me. Just initialize the model with the first value. The `ng-init="myItem = items[0].name"` does the trick

```
<select ng-if="items" ng-init="myItem = items[0].name" ng-model="myItem">
     <option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-value="item.name">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```