# How the options query works to show option for data present in array

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi i am learning ionic framework for mobile app development & have doubt in formulating the query for options to show.

Query Html:

```
<select ng-repeat="formEach in form" ng-options="f.FormId as f.Formname for f in form"></select>
```

My form array is this:

```
var form= [{Teamid : 1, Teamname :'First team', Formid: X0001, Formname : 'sample form 1'},
{Teamid : 2, Teamname :'Second team', Formid: X0002, Formname : 'sample form 2'},
{Teamid : 3, Teamname :'Third team', Formid: X0003, Formname : 'sample form 3'},
{Teamid : 4, Teamname :'Fourth team', Formid: X0004, Formname : 'sample form 4'}];
```

Comment: @Shaggie my answer will solve your problem, if you have a blank option you can look at the example

Comment: Your strings aren't wrapped in quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use ng-repeat and ng-options together. Also, set the model that will contain the selected option.

```
<select ng-model="Formid" ng-options="f.Formid for f in form track by f.Teamid"></select>
```

Your controller should look something like this..

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.form = [{
        Teamid: 1,
        Teamname: "First team",
        Formid: "X0001",
        Formname: "sample form 1"
    }, {
        Teamid: 2,
        Teamname: "Second team",
        Formid: "X0002",
        Formname: "sample form 2"
    }, {
        Teamid: 3,
        Teamname: "Third team",
        Formid: "X0003",
        Formname: "sample form 3"
    }, {
        Teamid: 4,
        Teamname: "Fourth team",
        Formid: "X0004",
        Formname: "sample form 4"
    }];
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamjld/L4kbok9d/)

Comment: ya this solves my problem. One more thing what to do if i need to have an attribute id for the options that will contain teamid probably???

Comment: it should be like <option id="1">sample form 1</option> ??

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array you can use ng-options like this :

```
      <select ng-model="Formid" ng-options="f as f.Formname for f in form"></select>
```

Look this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104565/angular-ng-options-remove-blank-option-and-select-the-first-option-only/30104741#30104741)

Comment: what about ng-model. it is not populating data