# Angular ng-options remove blank or set default option in special select settings

Tags: html, angularjs

I need remove this blank or set default value because when I post form to the API I don't have all elements in array, but I need it, because not selected selects, they are not passing to json.

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104565/angular-ng-options-remove-blank-option-and-select-the-first-option-only) I find answer but here is simple example.
I have more complicated select and I don't know how remake this.
My select is in table, which td is generated dynamically and look like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="articleItem in articleColors">
    <td><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></td>
    <td>{{ articleItem.nazwa_art }}</td>
    <td>{{ articleItem.kolory_pod }}{{ articleItem.pantony }}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="m in [] | rangeFilter:0:pyNumber">  
        <select id="articleColorsData" name="py{{$index+1}}" class="form-control" ng-model="articleColorsData.kolory[$index]">
            <option value="x" selected>x</option>
            <option ng-repeat="oneColor in articleItem.all_colors" ng-selected="" value="{{ oneColor }}">{{ oneColor }}</option>
        </select>  
    </td>                                          
</tr>
```

I was trying with my select with ng-option, but it not working. I have errors that the $index is undefined.
I made something like that:

```
<select id="articleColorsData" name="py{{$index+1}}" 
ng-model="articleColorsData.kolory[$index]" 
ng-options="oneColor.value as oneColor.name for oneColor in articleItem.all_colors"></select>
```

And in cotroller:

```
$scope.articleColorsData.kolory[$index] = $scope.articleItem.all_colors[0].value;
```

All code form controller:

```
appPokayoke.controller('CreateArticleColorsCtr', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', 'articles', '$location', 'articlesOfDrawings', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, articles, $location, articlesOfDrawings, rangeFilter ) {


        var drawingId = $routeParams.drawingId;
        var pyNumber = $routeParams.pyNumber;
        var articleName = $routeParams.articleName;



        $scope.pyNumber = $routeParams.pyNumber;

        $scope.articleColors = {};
        $scope.articleColorsData = {
        "id_rys" : drawingId, 
        "ile_py" : pyNumber, 
        "nazwa_art" : articleName
        };

        $scope.articleColorsData.kolory[$index] = $scope.articleItem.all_colors[0].value;

        articles.getNewArticle(
            $routeParams.articleName, 
            $routeParams.drawingId,
            function (data) {
                if(data !== '') {
                    $scope.articleColors = data;

                }
                else {
                    console.log('not ok articleColors');  
                }
            }
        );  
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the second thing - set default value, which was the better way for me but the blank is still there.
The code is the same like I had at the beginning.
I only added to select this code:

```
ng-init="articleColorsData.kolory[$index] = 'x'"
```

My full code:

```
<td ng-repeat="m in [] | rangeFilter:0:pyNumber">  
    <select id="articleColorsData" name="py{{$index+1}}" class="form-control" ng-model="articleColorsData.kolory[$index]" ng-init="articleColorsData.kolory[$index] = 'x'">
        <option ng-repeat="oneColor in articleItem.all_colors" ng-value="x"  value="{{ oneColor }}">{{ oneColor }}</option>
    </select>  
</td>
```