# ignore empty value from the list

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I am iterating list of objects using ng-options and while displaying in the UI components ( drop-down select ) first value in the list coming as `empty` value. How can I ignore that empty value from the list to display.

Please find my code below. Also, I was writing this code in my JSP file.

```
<select class = "form-control" form-control id = "lenProperty" ng-model = "bank.lendPropertyId"  
 ng-options="lenProperty.id 
                       as lenProperty.lendPropertyName for lenProperty in lenProperties">
</select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular ng-options remove blank option and select the first option only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104565/angular-ng-options-remove-blank-option-and-select-the-first-option-only)

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore empty values by changing the way you are creating the `<select>`:

```js
 
   <select class = "form-control" id = "lenProperty"  ng-model="bank.lendPropertyId">
    <option ng-repeat="lenProperty in lenProperties" ng-show="lenProperty.lendPropertyName">{{lenProperty.lendPropertyName}}</option>
</select>
```